# Check if a row in one data frame exist in another data frame but do not merge both data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (df_validation) in which I have done some validation. If all was ok, this should be empty. If not, rows with info like this will be found

```
CHR  START  END
1    1000   2000 # Imagine this failed
```

Now, I want to communicate to another data frame (df) that validation was ok except for the ones that appear in df_validation

This is df

```
CHR  START  END
1    1000   2000
2    1000   2000
3    1000   2000
4    1000   2000
5    1000   2000
```

and this is the result I would like to have

```
CHR  START  END    Pass_validation?
1    1000   2000      False
2    1000   2000      True
3    1000   2000      True
4    1000   2000      True
5    1000   2000      True
```

How can I do this? The first idea was to merge both but having same column name, it adds a '_X' on left and '_Y' on right. The new right columns I don't really need, just a new column as in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use `indicator=True` parameter for helper column `_merge` and for `False` for match compare for not equal `both`. If is omit `on` parameter is joined by intersection of columnsname in both dataFrames, here `CHR`, `START` and `END`.

```
df2['Pass_validation?'] = df2.merge(df_validation, 
                                    indicator=True, 
                                    how='left')['_merge'].ne('both')
print (df2)
    CHR  START  END  Pass_validation?
0  1    1000   2000             False
1  2    1000   2000              True
2  3    1000   2000              True
3  4    1000   2000              True
4  5    1000   2000              True
```

**Details**:

```
print (df2.merge(df_validation, indicator=True, how='left'))
    CHR  START  END     _merge
0  1    1000   2000       both
1  2    1000   2000  left_only
2  3    1000   2000  left_only
3  4    1000   2000  left_only
4  5    1000   2000  left_only
```